# Copying a collection of entites

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to copy a list of users roles from one user to another with the method:

```
public bool CopyUsersRoles(Guid copyFromUserId, Guid copyToUserId)
{
    //Delete existing roles for user
    var rolesToDelete = context.UserApplicationRoles.Where(x => x.UserID == copyToUserId);

    foreach (var u in rolesToDelete)
    {
        context.UserApplicationRoles.DeleteObject(u);
    }    

    var rolesToAdd = context.UserApplicationRoles.Where(x => x.UserID == copyFromUserId)
                                  .ToList();                             

    for(int i = 0; i < rolesToAdd.Count; i++)
    {
        rolesToAdd[i].UserID = copyToUserId;                           
    }    

    foreach (var u in rolesToAdd)
    {
        context.UserApplicationRoles.AddObject(u);
    }    

    context.SaveChanges();    
}
```

I am getting the following exception when assigning a new `UserId`:

> The property 'UserID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. 
>        at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.VerifyEntityValueIsEditable(StateManagerTypeMetadata typeMetadata, Int32 ordinal, String memberName)

I would have thought that the ToList() would have prevented this...

What is the correct way to achieve this?

**EDIT - class details:**

[image]

I see there is no PK set on the legacy table. I'm assuming manually setting the PK to UserApplicationRoleId will fix this.

UserId Looks like this:

```
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Guid UserID
    {
        get
        {
            return _UserID;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_UserID != value)
            {
                OnUserIDChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("UserID");
                _UserID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("UserID");
                OnUserIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to add the roles to the user roles collection, not changing the userID!!!

Comment: I need to take the existing roles, create a copy of them with the new userid and then add the ones with the new id to the collection. Im probably missing something very obvious here!

Comment: Can you post the `Role` class?

Comment: The class is actually called UserApplicationRole...I just simplified it for the example. Its an EntityObject so the class is pretty big: I'll try post the relevant bits - give me a few mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up getting this to work in a pretty nasty way (the legacy DB doesn't have auto incrementing PKs :(

```
            var copyToUser = this.GetUser(copyToUserId);
            List<UserApplicationRole> userApplicationRoles = new List<UserApplicationRole>();
            int startingId = Convert.ToInt32(isignonContext.UserApplicationRoles.OrderByDescending(u => u.UserApplicationRoleId).FirstOrDefault().UserApplicationRoleId) + 1;

            foreach (var u in userApplicationRolesToAdd)
            {
                UserApplicationRole userApplicationRole = new UserApplicationRole
                {
                    UserApplicationRoleId = startingId,
                    UserID = copyToUser.UserId,
                    UserGroupId = copyToUser.ParentId.Value,
                    ApplicationRoleId = u.ApplicationRoleId,
                    ExpiryDate = u.ExpiryDate,
                    IsEnabled = u.IsEnabled
                };

                userApplicationRoles.Add(userApplicationRole);
                startingId++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
  var rolesToAdd = context.UserApplicationRoles
  .Where(x => x.UserID == copyFromUserId)                             
  .ToList();  

   ....

  foreach (var u in rolesToAdd)
  {
    context.UserApplicationRoles.AddObject(u);
  }
```

You are referencing objects that are already in DB/EF. You must make a clone of these and add  clones to EF.